# How do I create objects in between two points with an offset?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am wondering on how to do this
in Pic1 SEG3.For example, I know how to do whats in SEG1/SEG2 with this `Vector3 position = controlPoints[i].position + j *(controlPoints[i + 1].position - controlPoints[i].position) / segCount;`(*For more about the code visit [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1226054/how-do-i-instantiate-gameobjects-in-between-multip.html) its an old question I asked about dividing between two points*),

but I want to know how to do this in SEG3(which we'll come around in second). As you can see in SEG2 when I move it, the subPoints will always stay in the center, but I want to know how to move it like in SEG3 so that sub points stay specific distance(int distanceCP) away from the controlPoints, would anyone know how to do this??

Pic1
[image]

---

**Here is the code that does SEG1/SEG2.**

```
public class Points : MonoBehaviour
  {
      public Transform[] points;
      public GameObject GameObj;
      public float GameObjectAmount = 2;
      void Start()
      {
          duplicateObject(GameObj, (int) GameObjectAmount);
      }
      public void duplicateObject(GameObject original, int howmany)
      {
          howmany++;
          for (int i = 0; i < points.Length-1; i++)
          {
              for (int j = 1; j < howmany; j++)
              {
                  Vector3 position = points[i].position + j * (points[i + 1].position - points[i].position) / howmany;
                  Instantiate(original, position, Quaternion.identity);
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Would `Vector3.Lerp` help you?

Comment: The pics describe the spawning behaviour for only 2 objects. How the points should be placed if they are more than 2..? or you want exactly 2 objects all the time?

Comment: Hold on i forgot to change Pic1 in the post, there we go i have changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with Unity's [Ray](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray.html) API. You can use it to modify both `controlPoints`.

```
controlPoint1 = somePos;
controlPoint2 = someOtherPos;
```

then use [Ray's](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray.html) `GetPoint` function to get the offset of `controlPoint1`.

```
var offsetDistance = 5;
Ray myRay= new Ray();
offsetRayFrom.origin = controlPoint1 ;
offsetRayFrom.direction = controlPoint2 - controlPoint1 ;
Vector3 newFromDisance = offsetRayFrom.GetPoint(offsetDistance);
controlPoint1 = newFromDisance; //Change 'From' Distance
```

Now, do the-same thing to the `controlPoint2` position, but flip the origin and direction values, then you can now use those two new values(Vector3) in your `for` loop.

I couldn't understand your code so I modified my personal position to chunk positions function to include `offset` parameter. It is commented. You can read the comments to understand what's going on under the hood.

It takes the 2 positions (`controlPoint1` and `controlPoint2`), then a `Vector3` array to store the result, followed by chunk amount(howmany), `bool` to tell it if to use offset or not, then finally the distance offset. *I did not make the function return an array. I made it to fill in what array that is passed in to the `result` parameter. This is good for memory management*.

```
void posToChunkDistances(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, Vector3[] result, int chunkAmount, bool useOffset = false, float offsetDistance = -1f)
{

    //Change from and to values if we want to use offset
    if (useOffset)
    {
        Debug.Log("Use Offset");

        //Un-Comment to Allow negative offset?
        //offsetDistance = Mathf.Abs(offsetDistance);

        //Find new 'From' Distance
        Ray offsetRayFrom = new Ray();
        offsetRayFrom.origin = from;
        offsetRayFrom.direction = to - from;
        Vector3 newFromDisance = offsetRayFrom.GetPoint(offsetDistance);
        from = newFromDisance; //Change 'From' Distance


        //Find new 'To' Distance
        Ray offsetRayTo = new Ray();
        offsetRayTo.origin = to;
        offsetRayTo.direction = from - to;
        Vector3 newToDisance = offsetRayTo.GetPoint(offsetDistance);
        to = newToDisance; //Change 'To' Distance
    }

    //divider must be between 0 and 1
    float divider = 1f / chunkAmount;
    float linear = 0f;

    if (chunkAmount == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError("chunkAmount Distance must be > 0 instead of " + chunkAmount);
        return;
    }

    if (chunkAmount == 1)
    {
        result[0] = Vector3.Lerp(from, to, 0.5f); //Return half/middle point
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < chunkAmount; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            linear = divider / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            linear += divider; //Add the divider to it to get the next distance
        }
        // Debug.Log("Loop " + i + ", is " + linear);
        result[i] = Vector3.Lerp(from, to, linear);
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
public GameObject testCubePrefab;
public Transform dst1;
public Transform dst2;

void Start()
{
    int myDistances = 2;
    Vector3[] distancesResult = new Vector3[myDistances];
    posToChunkDistances(dst1.position, dst2.position, distancesResult, myDistances, true, 5f);

    for (int i = 0; i < distancesResult.Length; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(testCubePrefab, distancesResult[i], Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this work for multiple points like this in this Pic http://i.imgur.com/rml2tLM.png, sorry i forgot to change Pic1 in the post(i have now changed it).

Comment: @TheRapidSloth You are are not sorry for anything. Please Do **not** heavily modify your question like you did. You got a working solution from me then you changed your whole question.This is not how to ask a question. You create a new question for stuff like this. I rolled back your question to reflect your original question which was (create objects between two points not 4 points).The good news is that it will still work.

Answer (score 1):

Vector3.distance give you the distance from first to second control point.
Divide or make a vector in the first position with your new distance (distaceCP). Make same in the other control point and invert vector direction.
Place your object in the end of each created vector and you got it.

Or simply use MoveToward to move your object from A to B.

```
Object1.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(PosB, PosA, step);
Object2.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(PosA, Posb, step);
```